# Can vscode run pytests at the folder level instead of just running all tests or only a single test?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

My project structure looks something like this:

```
├── myproject
├── conftest.py
├── pytest.ini
└── tests
    ├── fixtures
    ├── integration
    └── unit
```

In pytest.ini I have this:

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests/unit
project_name = myproject
```

90% of the time I just want to run unit tests. I don't want to run integration tests as often because they take longer and are less safe then unit tests because they actually do stuff

So I put them in another folder, set unit as the default folder and whenever I want to run them I just do: `py.test tests/integration` or `py.test tests` to run all unit and integration tests. I avoided pytest annotations because my needs are simple and using two folders seemed like a lot less config overhead.

This works really well for me but now I want to take advantage of vscode's pytest support. It's only picking up tests in the "unit" folder which must mean it's reading that from `pytest.ini`. I changed `pytest.ini` to just have the top level "test" folder and vscode found both of them.

But vscode seems to provide no way to only run one set of test (via its folder). For example I can't find out how to just run "unit" tests in the test window:

[image]

So how do I have vscode run all unit tests by default and also optionally run integration tests *ad hoc*?

Is it possible to have multiple run configurations for tests? There is a `python.testing.cwd` param, is there a way I could have two test run configurations and set python.testing.cwd to a different value for each of them and then choose which one I want to run from the vscode test window?

Answer (score 0):

I would really like the feature of being able to run a test on the folder level with a little play button on the right (how it does it for the module level).

As a bad workaround, I just add fields to ignore specific tests in your config (workspace or whatnot) when I need too.

```
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "--ignore=integration",
    ],
```

Comment: Seems like this feature was included in a recent update